# Docker ModuleNotFoundError : No module named vcolors

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker, I've tried several fixes that I found here on Stack Overfow but wasn't abe to sove the issue.

I'm getting this error when I try to:

```
docker run app
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /PedidoCriado

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH /PedidoCriado

COPY . /PedidoCriado/

CMD [ "python", "/PedidoCriado/PedidoCriado.py" ]
```

My requirements.txt:

```
autopep8==1.6.0
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
colored==1.4.3
idna==3.3
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
klaviyo-sdk==1.0.1.20211126
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
pipedrive-python-lib==1.1.5
pycodestyle==2.8.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.19.2
requests==2.27.1
six==1.16.0
tenacity==8.0.1
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==1.26.8
vcolors==1.0
Werkzeug==2.0.2
```

And this is my folder structure:

```
├── projectFoder
│   ├── PedidoCriado
│      ├── PedidoCriado.py
│      ├── Dockerfile
│      └── requirements.txt
```

Comment: Is there really any package named vcolors? Isn't it only colors ? 
https://pypi.org/project/colors.py/

Comment: Yes, check this screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/26mqksm